# Prove inverse dependence of a variable

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let there be an equation,

$(c+y)x-yd=N$

Here, $c>0$, $d$, and $N$ are fixed constants, while $x\geq0$ is the variable, and $y>0$ is a parameter.

Now, intuitively, increasing the parameter $y$ should change $x$ such that the absolute difference $|x-d|$ is reduced, for the equation to remain satisfied.

However, how can a formal proof of the above statement be given?

Answer (score 1):

expanding your function and solving w.r.t. $y$ you get

$$y=\frac{cx-N}{e-x}$$

taking the derivative you get

$$y'=\frac{ce-N}{(e-x)^2}$$

which is always positive or negative depending on the parameters' value

thus there is a negative dependence (your function is strictly decreasing) if

$$ce<N$$

further constraints are needed on the parameters so that $y\geq 0$

---

$e$ is not a nice choice for a parameter; usually it denotes Neper Constant.

Comment: What would happen if I also force 'y' to be a positive constant, and then increase 'y' as a parameter. Will the difference |x-e| then decrease monotonically with increase in parameter 'y'?

Comment: Moreover, the derivative of 'y' given above is w.r.t to 'x'. Should I not calculate the change of 'y' with respect to |x-d| ? (notation change: 'e' changed to 'd')